# How to fix truncated syntax highlighting in Xcode for Macron Characters

Tags: c++, xcode

In my project, I'm attempting to use identifiers with Macrons in them (which is perfectly valid, and everything still compiles).

The problem is that Xcode truncates syntax highlighting after the first occurrence of a character with a macron.

The standard answers for text highlighting issues have been:

- Turn it off and on again.
- Delete Derived Data, and turn it off and on again.

I've tried both with no success.

[image]

This example photo uses typedef to demonstrate the issue. For reference, `ira` and `tōpū` both roughly equate to `float` and `int`.

As you can see, the highlighting stops after the first t of tōpū, but ira is fully highlighted.

I would like to know how to get Xcode to recognise the macron characters and continue highlighting the entire identifier. Thanks!

Comment: There are two ways in Unicode to represent "ō": 1) as a single character, U+014D, LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH MACRON; 2) as a plain "o" followed by a combining macron character, U+006F LATIN SMALL LETTER O followed by U+0304 COMBINING MACRON. Try copying this single-character "ō" from my comment and pasting it into your identifiers to see if that help.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and am still getting the problem.

Comment: Oh, well. If you haven't already, you should file a bug with Apple.